# Why do I get prompted when I attempt to delete my project?

Tags: ios, bash, rm, podfile

I just did

```
rm -r projectName
```

then I got:

```
override r--r--r--  honey/staff for projectFolder//.git/objects/pack/pack-9323e9c7e9a036b5f0f9186d05e31536e342308.pack?
```

Based on a Google search, I know I won’t be prompted to such if I `rm -rf`

But still can’t understand what restrictions are in place that result in such a prompt, nor know how to get out of it once prompted.

I ran `ls -l projectName` and got:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 honey staff 12409 Mar 19 10:31 Podfile.lock
```

Not sure if that means anything. 
Can anyone help opening this up?

Comment: It shows a file that is `r--r--r--`  which is missing write permission

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @Cyrus I just wonder that it has something to do with cocoapods, so I'm not 100% sure if I should move the question...

Comment: `rm` does have a `-f` "force" option if you really want to blow your foot off without anyone asking you if you're sure.